# Normal distribution with a conditional probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given this Normal Distribution:

[image]

Find:

[image]

RE the conditional probability I don't understand how the mark scheme got the numerator. If we have P(120 < B < 146) then we get:

= P(B < 146) - P(B < 120)

= phi(1.99) - phi(-0.6289)

= phi(1.99) - (1 - phi(0.6289)

= 0.9767 - (1 - 0.7357)

but they have = 0.7357 - (1 - 0.9767)

**Mark scheme:**

[image]

Comment: $0.9767 - (1 - 0.7357) = 0.7357 - (1 - 0.9767)$

Comment: The left hand side is $P(Z\le 1.99) - P(Z\le -0.6289)$ while the right hand side is $P(Z\gt -0.6289) - P(Z\gt 1.99)$  so both are $P(-0.6289 \lt Z \le  1.99)$

Comment: Got it. I had right answer. Just seemed an odd way to show it.